# Magento FPC cron error

Tags: magento-1.9, full-page-cache

We've been using FPC for a while now and it seems to be doing the trick, we've just had this error start appearing with regards to the fpc log cron.

`Next Zend_Db_Statement_Exception: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '5524522' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT INTO m_fpc_log`

Has anyone had this issue before? Should I just truncate this table?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason it's trying to create another entry with the same ID which must be unique.

If you delete this entry only, it should be working fine.

Comment: If I do a search in the table for `5524522` nothing is found, I have noticed that the next AI is `5524522` though... it seems strange.

Comment: truncate the table. I am sure it is there somewhere, but as it's a log it can be truncated.